# NoClassDefFoundError after changing a class to different module

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Java spring boot, Gradle 6 and IntelliJ.
I moved a class from module X to module Y, and added it to module X's build.gradle of module Y (for legacy dependencies):

```
plugins {
    id "java-library"
}
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {

    implementation project(":the-new-class-module-y")
}
```

I fixed all import classpath changes and the application is running as expected, except for a single uni-test class that is falling due to NoClassDefFoundError.

I checked the Gradle dependencies of module X and module Y exist there.
There are also no errors in IntelliJ at all.
I tried Gradle rebuild, Gradle refresh, Gradle clean build, invalid cache - nothing helped. Gradle run finished successfully.

More details:
I have a ContractsController with this import:
`import com.x.interactors.ResponseInteractor`, and it works fine. Then, for the same controller ContractsControllerTest with uni-test, I use the same import:
`import com.x.interactors.ResponseInteractor`, but it gets java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

It happens only when I run  `./gradlew check -x :component-test:check`.

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: There is not enough detail to solve it. Does the error happen when you run gradle from the command line or only when running tests in IntelliJ?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki No, Gradle finished successfully. I only see this error when I run  ./gradlew check -x :component-test:check.

Comment: Close IntelliJ. Delete the .idea directory (and *.iml, *.iwp, *.iws files) and re-import the project cleanly into IntelliJ. If this doesn't help use File > Invalidate Caches.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I did it and it still failed. I will be happy to provide more details but I'm not sure what will help. Can you guide me, please?

Comment: I have a ContractsController with this import:
import com.x.interactors.ResponseInteractor, and it works fine.
Then, for the same controller but with uni-test, I use the same import:
import com.x.interactors.ResponseInteractor, but it gets java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.